# Max duration for capture video on android

Tags: android, video, android-intent, video-capture

I have code for capturing a video clip on Android:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 30000);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY", 0);
startActivityForResult(intent, ActivityRequests.REQUEST_TAKE_VIDEO);
```

This code works well on API 2.2, but the duration limit does not work on API 2.1 (Galaxy S). Is there some constant or parameter for setting this time, or is there a better approach than the one I am taking?

I ask because I found another application that works on the Galaxy S (called `Vibrant`) which can record video for a short amount of time.

Comment: Well, what I can say, in Android 1.6, there is no constant MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT as in 2.2. So there should be another solution then using this extra.

Comment: I have this problem in android 2.2.1 Droid.

Comment: I got error in ActivityRequests ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**android.intent.extra.durationLimit** was introduced in API Level 8, so it's not available in Eclair and earlier, unfortunately. Some device manufacturers may have a proprietary way to set the maximum duration on older devices, which explain why you have seen this working on some pre-Froyo applications.

Comment: @dmtribdv, you can see the API level at which each variable is introduced by looking to the right side of the gray bar on the Android resources site. For example, see this variable (and it's API level) here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT

Comment: Yes I can see the API levels there and I am using this for 2.2.1 which abides to API 8 though

Answer (score 0):

For your information it does not run on HTC devices. welcome to the android world.