# How to increase the duration of Video recording in android?

Tags: android, video

I use the MediaStore to capture the video, but it will record the video upto 8 seconds only ,can anyone help me to increase the duration of video. I am using android 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT)

Specify an EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT parameter in the `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` Intent.

From [StackOverflow - Max duration for capture video on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853783/max-duration-for-capture-video-on-android)

`intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 30000);`

Comment: i got an toast , size limit reached ,what to do